# How do you create a transparent truecolor PNG with Perl & GD?

Tags: perl, png, transparency, gd

It seems like a trivial problem, but nothing I've tried will make the background transparent.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use GD

GD::Image->trueColor(1);
my $im = new GD::Image(100, 100);

my $clear = $im->colorAllocateAlpha(255, 255, 255, 127);
my $black = $im->colorAllocateAlpha(0, 0, 0, 0);

$im->alphaBlending(0);
$im->filledRectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, $clear);

$im->alphaBlending(1);
$im->stringFT($black, "a-ttf-font.ttf", 12, 0, 20, 20, "x");

binmode STDOUT;
print $im->png;
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: -1 You must use `strict` and `warnings`. Code you post must be the code you run. You have `$image`, `$im` and `$img`. What the Frack?

Comment: it was *some* of the code I run. Fixed.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you want the text to appear grey? Oh, and I forgot to vote the question down.

Comment: I'm looking to create a PNG with a fully transparent background and anti-aliased black text.

The transparent background is my primary objective though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using `$im->saveAlpha(1)`? Otherwise the alpha information is only useful in constructing the image. The saved image won't be transparent.

A quick and dirty method, which might not be good enough for your purposes, is to forget about the alpha channel and use the [`GD::Image::transparent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?GD) method.

Comment: Thanks, that's the one! Can't believe I didn't spot that.